# Quotient ring being isomorphic to the initial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This may be a very basic question.

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity (may be assumed to be an integral domain, if necessary) and $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Assume that $R/I$ is isomorphic to $R$. Does this mean $I=(0)$ ?

Comment: Just a side note, “initial ring” might be interpreted as “the [initial object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects) in the category of Rings with unity”, which is $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Counterexample:

$R=\Bbb Q [X_1, X_2, \dots , X_n, \dots]$. Define the ring morphism $f: R \to R$ by
$$\begin{cases}X_i \mapsto X_{i-1} & i>1 \\ X_1 \mapsto 0
\end{cases}
$$

and call $I= \ker f$.

Then $$R/I \cong \mathrm{Im} f= R$$

Answer (score 13):

There's a subtlety here: what do you mean by "is isomorphic to"?

In a setting where the constructions of $A$ and/or $B$ yield a canonical map $f:A \to B$, the phrase "$A$ is isomorphic to $B$" is often used as shorthand for saying the *specific map* $f$ is an isomorphism, rather than merely asserting there exists some map that is an isomorphism.

And it is true that, if the quotient map $R \to R/I$ is an isomorphism, then $I = (0)$.

But if you simply assert there is *some* isomorphism between $R$ and $R/I$ without implicitly requiring it to be the quotient map, then it is indeed possible for $I$ to be nontrivial as demonstrated in the other answer. For variety, I will give another example.

Let $R = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \cdots$ be the product of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ (let's say, countably many).

There is a surjective "forget the first component and shift left by one place" map $R \to R$ whose kernel is $I = \mathbb{Z} \times 0 \times 0 \times \cdots $. Then, you have $R \cong R/I$.

Comment: It is worth noting that if $R$ and $R/I$ are isomorphic *as $R$-algebras*, then $I$ must be trivial.

Comment: Why a non-specific isomorphism between $R$ and $R/I$ as $R$- algebras will make $I$ trivial? @tomasz

Comment: @Sam: To be slightly more specific, I guess it implies that $I$ is trivial in the sense that $RI=0$. This is easy to see, as $R/I\cdot I=0$.

Comment: My current interest is in the following for which I hope the answer to be true but unable to prove it. Let $D\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n$ be a domain and $\mathcal{O}_{D}$ be the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $D$. Define the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}_{D}:=\mathcal{O}_{D}f_{1}+\cdots +\mathcal{O}_{D}f_{k}$. Now, for each fixed $x\in D$, we have $\mathcal{O}_{D,x}/\mathcal{I}_{D,x}\simeq \mathcal{O}_{D,x}$ as $\mathbb{C}$-algebras. Does this mean that $\mathcal{I}_{D,x}\simeq {0}$ for each $x\in D$ or equivalently, $\mathcal{I}_{D}={0}?$ - Does this go along the lines of what you said? @tomasz

Comment: Are you trying to prove that $f_1,\ldots,f_k$ are all zero? Because otherwise, $\mathcal I_D$ is not zero.

Comment: @Sam: An $R$-algebra structure on a ring $S$ is determined by the action on the identity: $r \cdot s = r \cdot (1_S s) = (r \cdot 1_S)s$, and $r \mapsto r \cdot 1_S$ gives a homomorphism $R \to S$ (conversely, every such homomorphism gives an $R$-algebra structure on $S$). If you compute $R/I$ as a quotient of $R$-algebras rather than as a quotient of rings, the $R$-algebra structure on $R/I$ is the one whose corresponding homomorphism is the quotient map.

Comment: @tomasz: Yes and I think the following argument settles it. Suppose one of them, say $f_{1}$ is not zero. Then $\exists x\in D$ s.t. $f_{1}(x)\neq 0$. Consequently, $f_{1x}$ is an unit in $\mathcal{O}_{D,x}$. But $f_{1x}\in\mathcal{I}_{D,x}$ which is an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{D,x}$. So, $\mathcal{I}_{D,x}=\mathcal{O}_{D,x}$, which implies $\mathcal{O}_{D,x}/\mathcal{I}_{D,x}\simeq 0$ contradicting the hypothesis of it being isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{D,x}$ for this particular $x$.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Thanks for the illustration.

Comment: @Sam: I don't think you need to go to local rings for that. It's just that if any $f_i$ is nonzero, then $\mathcal I_D$ contains a nonzero element (namely, $f_i$), so it cannot be zero. I did not think much about what you're asking, but I suspect you're overthinking it.

Comment: What I meant is, if for each $x\in D$, we have $\mathcal{O}_{D,x}/\mathcal{I}_{D,x}\simeq\mathcal{O}_{D,x}$, then it is settled that $f_{1},\ldots,f_{k}$ are all zero(which, trivially is equivalent to $\mathcal{I}_{D}$ being zero, as you mentioned).