# When can a ring be isomorphic to a quotient of itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let's consider more general situation. Let $R$ be a ring and $I\subset R$ be an ideal of it. Fix a homomorphism
$$
f: R\to R/I
$$
where $f$ is **not** necessarily the quotient map. Suppose $f$ happens to be an isomorphism of rings, then can we conclude $I=(0)$?

The question is inspired by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2758428/quotient-ring-being-isomorphic-to-the-initial-ring) where the answer is negative. But examples there more or less involve some infinite direct products. I doubt that this kind of examples may not exist if we work with some ring like the polynomial algebra $R=\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.

> Question: Maybe with some reasonable conditions (like noetherian), we can actually show $I=(0)$.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What exactly do you want? Are you looking for conditions so that $I=0$, or do you have a specific scenario and you want to know whether $I=0$ must hold there?

Comment: Do you want R Noetherian? Otherwise too many examples! cowsik

Comment: No: consider the product ring $R^X$ over an infinite set $X$. The $X$-tuples vanishing at a fixed $x\in X$ make an ideal $I$ and $R^X/I\cong R^{X\setminus\{x\}}$, but the latter ring is isomorphic to $R^X$, because of cardinality.

Comment: @R.C.Cowsik If we assume R is noetherian, can we find an example?

Comment: @KReiser Let’s find conditions so that it is necessary I=0